# Get Norton GoBack To Work On Windows Vista And Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, compatibility, norton-goback, disk-protection

Norton GoBack doesn't work with Windows Vista, or Windows 7, for reasons unknown. I have tried several alternatives including: Norton Ghost, RollbackRX, and Norton Save And Restore, but none of which offer the same functionality as Norton GoBack.

Not only does Norton GoBack not eat up all your hard drive space while creating a legitimate fail safe for any pc problems, it also allows you to actively see what processes are being executed on the computer. The Advanced Disk Drive Restore feature also allows you to troubleshoot problems, and determine causes for things quickly; it's how I learned everything I know about computers.

Norton GoBack also features something called Safe Try Mode where you can put it in Safe Try, mess up the whole computer, and when you come out of it your computer will be exactly how it was before. This is amazing for people who like to tinker without risking their machine's stability. It also helps for that accidentally erased papers, or whatever you may have removed.

In order to enable this functionality, I believe Norton GoBack installs a type44 partition around the drive, which loads prior to Windows.

If you're going to recommend another program, please don't unless it does all of the above things. I've tried the competition's products, and nothing is as good. I just want my Norton GoBack to work with Windows 7! Any crazy ideas to get Norton GoBack working on Windows Vista, and Windows 7?

Comment: I searched the Symantec website for Norton GoBack; the query returned this: **Norton GoBack has been replaced by Norton Ghost 15** (http://searchg.symantec.com/search?q=goback&charset=utf-8&proxystylesheet=symc_en_US&client=symc_en_US&hitsceil=100&site=symc_en_US&output=xml_no_dtd&context=hho&x=0&y=0). Might want to check out Norton Ghost. I doubt you can make GoBack work with Vista or 7 and it's basically been discontinued.

Comment: He does mention he tried it, though I'm sure you're right that there is a succesor

Comment: Ghost doesn't have the same functionality at all. Even if I was ok with only having file backup as the functionality, ghost doesn't work in real time, meaning it won't help you if a problem prevents your computer from booting. 

Also, it does a whole disk copy each time, so a 150GB hard drive takes 150GB to back up. Even with a 300GB laptop hard drive that gives you one backup before everything is full. GoBack only records changes to the filesystem, meaning its be much less of a space hog.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain ... I have looked extensively for a GoBack replacement to no avail.  It is the reason I still have several PC's on WinXP.

For my Win7 machines I am using Acronis True Image... Nowhere near as good as goback, but its the closest I could find.  It gives you a restore point every 5 minutes and you can get files back (like with goback) with its "continuous backup".

Also, I use "System Change Log" by greyware.com to get close to the troubleshooting functionality of goback's advanced restore features by showing every change to your hard drive.

Please post back if you find out how to get it working on Win7

SteveG

Answer (score 1):

Use GoBack even though you have Windows 7 installed. This can be done by making a partition on the hard drive and installing Windows XP on it.

GoBack makes a backup image of the hard drives you select on installation, so if you mess up your computer you can simply start up with Windows XP, run GoBack and restore the partition where Windows 7 is installed to a time before you mess it up.

It's a lot of hassle but it's the only way I have found to fix errors with GoBack on Windows 7.